# How to include blade File in to the php file

Tags: php, laravel

page-standard.php file is my core file , then one of my file is test.blade.php file. So, the Question is that how can i include the test.blade.php file in page-standard.php

```
Start :: page-standard.php

 include(base_path().'/resources/views/vendor/voyager/dashboard/test.blade.php');

End :: page-standard.php
```

Comment: What do you mean "include the test.blade.php file in page-standard.php"? Why include blade files in .php files? Do you want to just show the blade template?

Comment: because i want to merge the voygear + aimeos package.In Voygear pacakge is all file extension is the .blade.php and aimeos file is all page is .php.

Answer (score 1):

You can just echo the view using the helper:

```
echo view('name-of-blade.blade');
```

However in your case you also have to publish / copy the file from the vendor to access it.

Comment: view not found in php file

Comment: Like I said, first you need to place it inside `resources/views`

Comment: The .blade extension should not be there, otherwise you'll get an error. It should be: echo view( 'name-of-blade' );